# Can I have a persistent PDO object which just accepts new variables to be bound from AJAX calls?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

If i would like to create an ajax search (user fills in form elements, upon any update to the form elements, the search results are updated live.)

Is it possible to create a persistent (prepared) PDO connection which only requires the new variables sent over ajax to be bound/executed?

Is there another smart way to do this?

**Edit:** Just to be clear, and maybe more specific: what I am looking for is *a persistent prepared statement across connections.*

Comment: Are you sure a stored procedure wouldn't be better suited for this?

Answer (score 3):

You can estabilish persistent connection using:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass, array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
));
```

That way if you have to reconnect on new request, PDO will use connection from the pool rather than create new one. If you use prepared statements with `prepare()` and `bindParam()` query will be compiled on the database side and run faster that usual query.

Some links on caching:

http://www.snipe.net/2009/03/quick-and-dirty-php-caching/

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch10_15.htm

http://mysqlhacker.com/kabir/performance/understanding-mysql-query-cache-for-php-developers-part-i.html

Comment: I understand that these are correct separately.  Prepared statements will be compiled on the database side and run faster - AND - and persistent connections will _try_ to use the same connection as last time... however I am unsure of how these will work together.  I am having a feeling just these basic 2 parts are not enough to achieve what I am looking for, which is a persistent prepared statement across connections.

Comment: Database engine will compile and cache passed query between connections. But aren't you trying to optimize too much?

Comment: It is for a tagging system, which can start to become intense on a relational database as datasets start to grow large (or so is my understanding.)  With an AJAX style search, this will add additional load, so I am trying to shave computation where possible.

Comment: @Tomasz Kowalczyk Very interesting, but as to your comment about optimizing too much, are there reasons not to do it?

Comment: That's the wrong way for me. Optimizing the time to connect won't give you any benefits. Cache query results in PHP, that's the way to go.

Comment: Can you point me in a good direction for learning more about caching the results in PHP?  How would this help if I wanted to bind new parameters to the query?

Comment: Preparing query removes the compiling part. Binding parameters is the thing you'll always need to do, even when manually concatenating query string with them. For links, see my updated query.

Comment: About "*If you use prepared statements with prepare() and bindParam() query will be compiled on the database side and run faster that usual query.*" - take a look at http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54638, it states that "*The PDO_MySQL driver defaults emulate_prepare to 1, which forces all prepared queries to be emulated by the driver.*", so server-side compiling or caching of prepared queries just won't happen by default.

Comment: Interesting insight, but it only states that you need to ensure that it is working like you expect, which is a necessity all the time.

Comment: @jeroen, the reason is that too often time is spent for optimizing things that are not bottlenecks.

Comment: @binaryLV That might be true, but in a system where you probably connect to a database only once / at one place, time spent is not an argument not to add an array to your connection string. I was wondering if there are any other drawbacks.

Comment: I know this is a super old q/a but im trying to understand connections.  If I close a persistent connection by assigning null, is it still cached somehow?  Similarly, if I don't assign null, will it be used when I ajax the script next time?  (I have to call a script about 1000 times in a row, to make inserts, and I want to reuse the connection.)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're talking about prepared statments here, not "connections".

There is no way to keep the same prepared statment between calls (ajax or not)

An alternative would be to store variables in a temporary table and to send the real request at the end of the process...